# What wildcard operators are supported in Kronos WFC searches?

Tags: kronos-workforce-central

What types of wildcard operators are supported when searching database entries in Kronos Workforce Central 6.3? Specifically when attaching jobs in the Organizational Map Editor.

I know that you can use asterisks `*` when searching for job codes, but are there any other modifiers that can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own experimentation seems to show that Kronos *partially* follows the list of [.Net operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions), but it doesn't seem to be an exact match. There also doesn't seem to be any official documentation to verify.

Based on my own testing, here is an incomplete list of search operators ***when searching jobs***:

### Supported search modifiers

- **Asterisk `*`**: Substitute for zero or more characters
- **Question Mark `?`**: Substitute for a single character

  - `????` = Any 4 character string
  - `S???` = Any 4 character string that starts with S
- **Underscore `_`**: Substitute for a single character

### Not supported

- **Brackets `{}`**
- **Exclamation Point `!`**
- **Lazy quantifier `*?`**

  - Question mark is interpreted as a random character

---

**Notes**

- Certain search fields in Kronos may not support wildcards, such as when editing Function Access Profiles
- Searches support [URL encoded characters](https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/ref_urlencode.asp) using `%`.

  - Spaces can be encoded as a plus `+` or as `%20`